# maximum value and a differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ a differentiable function with  $f(x) + f^{'}(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=0.$ Which is the maximum possible value of $f(1)?$

My attempt:
For $x >0$ we have
 $$e^xf(x) + e^xf^{'}(x) \leq e^x \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{d x} (e^x f(x)) dx \leq e^{x} \Rightarrow e^x f(x) \leq e^x -1 \Rightarrow f(1) \leq 1 - \frac{1}{e}$$

Now it is needed an example such that $f$ satisfies the conditions with $f(1) = 1 - \frac{1}{e}.$ Some could help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the same method to solve the equation $f+f’=1$. Btw, there are typos in your post? Check them.

Comment: thank you ! it worked